# Pandas : zscore among the groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, quartile

I am trying to find z score of values among the groups, so for example in the following data

```
df:

GROUP VALUE
 1     5
 2     2
 1     10
 2     20
 1     7
```

In Group 1 there are values 5, 10, 7. So now I am looking for their zscore in their group only

```
Sample Desired Output: 

GROUP VALUE Z_SCORE
 1     5     0.5
 2     2     0.01
 1     10    7
 2     20    8.3
 1     7     1.3
```

zscore above are not true calculated values, just a representation.

I am trying the following

```
def z_score(x):
   z = np.abs(stats.zscore(x))
   return z

df['Z_SCORE'] = df.groupby(['GROUP'])['Value'].apply(z_score)
```

but not able to do it successfully. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) instead `apply` for correct convert numpy arrays to new `Series` per groups:

```
from  scipy.stats import zscore

def z_score(x):
   z = np.abs(zscore(x))
   return z

df['Z_SCORE'] = df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].transform(z_score)

print (df)
   GROUP  VALUE   Z_SCORE
0      1      5  1.135550
1      2      2  1.000000
2      1     10  1.297771
3      2     20  1.000000
4      1      7  0.162221
```

Solution with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) is possible, but is necessary change function for return `Series` with index by each group:

```
def z_score(x):
   z = np.abs(zscore(x))
   return pd.Series(z, index=x.index)


df['Z_SCORE'] = df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].apply(z_score)
print (df)
   GROUP  VALUE   Z_SCORE
0      1      5  1.135550
1      2      2  1.000000
2      1     10  1.297771
3      2     20  1.000000
4      1      7  0.162221
```

Comment: for me apply also works, gives back a list.. can you please explain here the diff ? thanks

Comment: @iamklaus - advantage is `transform` convert values to Series by default, solution with apply is possible, please give me a sec.